# Not building after creating new extension using any template

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris, I created a new extension using one of the given templates but when trying to build using Ant showing “Build Failed” on console. Saying duplicate Types found but I have not created any Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created templates as like the existing one say for example yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess to your-extname-fulfilmentprocess then you should remove the extension form the localextensions.xml.